# HtmlString MVC 4 extension method chain

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a extension method like that to create a button span:

```
public static HtmlString Ext1(this HtmlHelper helper, string css)
{
   var tag = new TagBuilder("span");

   tag.AddCssClass(css);
   ...
   return new HtmlString(tag.ToString());
}
```

I created another extension to add Attributes to HtmlString... Like that:

```
public static HtmlString Ext2(this HtmlString helper, string attr)
{
   // need add attr to HtmlString and return
   return new HtmlString(newHtmlGenerated);
}
```

Using `@Html.Ext1("class1").Ext2("1234")` should create a span with the css and attr...

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It's not clear from your question. You can't pass a string of html into the `TagBuilder` constructor - it only accepts the name of a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @levelnis said, you cannot create a `TagBuilder` from Html, you can only create it from a tag name.  You have to use something that will parse the Html back into a concrete type that allows you to access the attibutes.  `XDocument` will do this nicely.  Try changing your `Ext2` method to this:

```
public static HtmlString Ext2(this HtmlString helper, string attr)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(helper.ToHtmlString());
    doc.Element(doc.Root.Name).SetAttributeValue("test", attr);
    return new HtmlString(doc.ToString());
}
```

`XDocument` is in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thanks, any way to turn that method independent of Tag name "span" ?

Comment: Just updated my answer so the "span" is no longer hard coded.  It will assume that the attribute you're adding is on the root node but I think that will work for you purpose.  You'll probably also want to add an additional parameter for the attribute name as well so that won't be hard coded either.